# Automating application start by using scripts on XP

Tags: windows-xp, script, boot, automation

When I come to work, I spent several boring minutes running my applications. I start IDE, mail client, web browser, bug tracking system, Total Commander, ProcessExplorer and DebugView. Most of those tools I use for everyday work. It takes long time to start them all.

Therefore, I have created a BAT file, and put calling all those apps inside. When I turn on my work PC, I simply can run this BAT and have time for making morning coffee. Nevertheless, I realized that using BAT second application starts only after the first one has been closed. Since I want all applications to start, is it any possibility I can do it with BAT file? I do not want to use startup mechanism from Windows XP…

Comment: Why not use the startup folder from XP? It's the easiest way; that't how I do it at work for starting about 6-7 apps.

Comment: Because I do not want always to start this set of applications. Sometimes I need to start Delphi and processExplorer, sometimes I need to start Visual Studio.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried using the [start](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/start.mspx?mfr=true) command.

> When you run a 32-bit graphical user
>   interface (GUI) application, cmd does
>   not wait for the application to quit
>   before returning to the command
>   prompt. This new behavior does not
>   occur if you run the application from
>   a command script.

There is a useful [guide to the start command here](http://www.computerhope.com/starthlp.htm).

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `start` command to spawn an application without waiting.

```
start app1.exe
start app2.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use vbscript as follows :

```
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
ObjShell.Exec("FullPath")
ObjShell.Exec("FullPath1")
ObjShell.Exec("FullPath2")
....
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to grab [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) and then make a script to set up various shortcuts to start those apps (say Ctrl+Alt+V for visual studio, Ctrl+Alt+D for delphi, etc...) then you can just hit those key combos on startup to start the programs you want.

Answer (score 0):

Create a batch script, and make entries of all the required applications that you want to open in it in the below format:

```
start "" /b PATH %ARGUMENT
```

For example:

```
start "" /b "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" %http://www.ibnlive.com
start "" /b "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office12\OUTLOOK.EXE"
```

You can run this batch script to open the applications once you login.